# Facebook style messaging system schema design

Tags: mysql, database-design, symfony1, doctrine

I'm looking to implement a facebook style messaging system (thread messages) into a site of mine.

Do you think this schema markup looks okay?

[image]

Doctrine schema.yml:

```
UserMessage:
  tableName: user_message
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(10), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    sender_id : { type: integer(10), notnull: true }
    sender_read: { type: boolean, default: 1 }
    subject: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    message: { type: string(1000), notnull: true }
    hash: { type: string(32), notnull: true }
  relations:
    UserMessageRecipient as Recipient:
      type: many
      local: id
      foreign: message_id
    UserMessageReply as Reply:
      type: many
      local: id
      foreign: message_id
UserMessageReply:
  tableName: user_message_reply
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(10), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    user_message_id as message_id: { type: integer(10), notnull: true }
    message: { type: string(1000), notnull: true }
    sender_id: { type: integer(10), notnull: true }
  relations:
    UserMessage as Message:
      local: message_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
UserMessageRecipient:
  tableName: user_message_recipient
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(10), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    user_message_id as message_id: { type: integer(10), notnull: true }
    recipient_id: { type: integer(10), notnull: true }
    recipient_read: { type: boolean, default: 0 }
```

When I a new reply is made,i'll make sure the boolean for "recipient_read" for each recipient is set to false and of course i'll make sure sender_read is set to false too.

I'm using a hash for the URL: http://example.com/user/messages/aadeb18f8bdaea49882ec4d2a8a3c062

(As the id will be starting from 1, i don't wish to have http://example.com/user/messages/1. Yeah, I could start incrementing from a bigger number, but i'd prefer to start at 1.)

Is this a good way to go about it? Your thoughts and suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: UserMessage and UserMessageReply both represent one class - a Message. I'd rathen created one class and related it to itself by a reply_id field. Read here about nest relations: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/zh#relationships:join-table-associations:self-referencing-nest-relations

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you go with this?  Was it done in rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the difference between user_message.created_at and user_message_recipient.created_at?

Same question for updated_at. (Later: I guess user_message_recipient.updated_at might be the time the recipient read the message. If that's the case, I'd prefer a more meaningful name.)

Did you consider digging into some source code for open source projects that are intended to be Facebook replacements?

> When I a new reply is made,i'll make sure the boolean for "recipient_read" for each recipient is set to false and of course i'll make sure sender_read is set to false too.

I hope that means the dbms will verify those Booleans are set correctly.

Comment: Hello mike,thank you for your reply. created_at, updated_at. This is a plugin behaviour of the ORM. Every record has a created_at field. ANd when a record is updated, it's updated_at field is updated accordingly. I like to have this behaviour. Oh, and yeah, the dbms will verify it, but do you have a better idea? I could have a thread table as suggested in the above comment and have parent_id, child_id. Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of those Booleans being declared in the database as "NOT NULL" and "DEFAULT FALSE". That guarantees they'll start out with the right values.

Answer (score 1):

What about this model?

```
MESSAGES              USER_MESSAGES
========              =============
id                    id
content               message_id
reply_message_id      recipent_id
                      read
                      trash
                      hide
```

Answer (score 0):

i also tried to create a message system using database, the most common flaw is forgot that every user have different state of read-unread message. i hardly showing in database scheme, but in short you must consider to create flag like isread for every user for every user_message and user_message_reply, so every user just see the unread message.